# Como ordenar a consulta na mesma ordem de um array usado no WhereIn?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Gostaria que o Laravel me retornasse uma lista de produtos onde o ID pertence a este array: `[12,5,1,8,16]`, mas ordenasse por id conforme a ordem do array!*

O que tenho até o momento:

```
 $produtos = Produto::whereIn('id', $ids)
        ->orderBy( adicionar aqui a ordem do array $ids )
        ->get();
```

onde `$ids` é a variável que contenha este array `[12,5,1,8,16]`.

Como posso fazer o `orderBy` desta forma?

Comment: Eu uso a versão 5.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Método 1

Talvez a solução melhor seria usar o `Collection` do Laravel, já que você está trazendo tudo com o `get`.

Na versão 5.5 do Laravel você poderia usar o `firstWhere` para fazer isso, fazendo a iteração sobre os `$ids` obtendo os valores conforme a posição deles:

Exemplo:

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {

     $produto = $produtos->firstWhere('id', '=', $id);
}
```

## Método 2

Além do mais, você poderia usar o `sortBy`para fazer a ordenação dos produtos:

```
 $sorter = static function ($produto) use ($ids) {
    return array_search($produto->id, $ids);
 };

 $produtos = Produtos::whereIn('id', $ids)->get()->sortBy($sorter);
```

Nesse segundo exemplo, `array_search` vai retornar a posição do `array` em que se encontra o `id`, fazendo com que a ordenação seja de acordo com a posição de `$ids`.

Veja a documentação do [array_search](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php)

**Nota**: Nesse segundo exemplo não fiz testes, mas provavelmente você pode querer usar `sortByDesc` ao invés de `sortBy`.

## Método 3

Dependendo da situação que você for usar isso, talvez ainda compense você utilizar o método `lists`, combinada com a iteração em `$ids`

```
  $produtos = Produto::whereIn('id', $ids)->lists('nome', 'id');

  foreach ($ids as $id) {
    if (isset($produto[$id]) {
       echo $produto[$id];
    }
  }
```

## Metodo 4

Esse creio que seja melhor aplicado ao seu caso. Fiz uma pesquisa na [documentação do Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-keyby) e encontrei essa belezura chamada `keyBy`.

Basicamente o que ele faz é transformar os índices da Collection de acordo com a chave passada. Nesse caso eu escolho o `id`.

Veja!

```
 $produtos = Produto::whereIn('id', $ids)->get()->keyBy('id');
```

Assim, você poderia fazer algo semelhante a operação do **metodo 3** explicado anteriormente, porém `$produtos[$id]` te daria acesso ao objeto `Produto`, ao invés de apenas o nome do mesmo.

## Método 5

A uma [pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176375/3096922) também que existe o mesmo questionamento que o seu. Eu particularmente não gostei muito da forma que foi feita, mas seria basicamente essa:

```
$rawOrder = DB::raw(sprintf('FIELD(id, %s)', implode(',', $ids)));

$produtos = Produto::whereIn('id', $ids)
                 ->orderByRaw($rawOrder)
                 ->get();
```

Observe que você usa o `implode` com uma vírgula para gerar um trecho de uma consulta SQL através do `DB::raw`. Dessa forma, por mais que eu ache esteticamente feio fazer assim, tenho que admitir que é melhor que a ordenação já venha do banco, do que ter que reprocessar tudo pelo PHP.

O `FIELD` tem como objetivo determinar a ordem que o `ORDER BY` deverá considerar quando ordenar por pelo campo `ID`. Ou seja, a query executada no banco será exatamente:

```
 SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY FIELD(id, 12, 5, 1, 8, 16);
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas opções. Testei de cara a segunda, porém está dizendo que o array_search deve receber dois arrays como parâmetros, parece que você sugeriu que eu passasse o id do produto no primeiro parâmetro, então como seria? Vou testar a primeira de qualquer forma.

Comment: @GabrielAugusto jovem, não existe isso... Eu fiz o [teste](https://repl.it/@wallacemaxters/ArraySearch). O `array_search` só recebe um `array` no segundo parâmetro.

Comment: Quanto à primeira resposta, "Method firstWhere does not exist.". Verifiquei a versão do laravel usando o php artisan --version, apontou 5.5.19. 

Eis o código: $produtos = Produto::whereIn('id', $ids)
            ->get();

        $array_produtos = [];

        foreach($ids as $id) {
            array_push($array_produtos, $produtos->firstWhere('id', '=', $id));
        }

Comment: Realmente, li errado. O array_search espera que o segundo parâmetro seja um array, estou dando um objeto, perdão.

Comment: Eu gostaria de usar o método 4, apenas não estou conseguindo entender como eu ordenaria após indexar. Quanto ao método 5, eu havia pesquisado e vi essa solução, mas não consegui entender direito também, de qualquer forma obrigado. Vou tentar uma das soluções até conseguir.

Comment: O método `5` ele usa o  `DB::Raw` que permite você escrever um trecho manual de uma SQL numa consulta Eloquent. Com isso, você poderá usar o `FIELD` para determinar a ordem que o Order by deverá considerar a ordenação.

Comment: Obrigado, acabei ficando com a opção 5

Comment: Beleza, @GabrielAugusto. Boa sorte, ai

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma cláusula `order by` tomando o array como base.

```
$ids = [12, 5, 1, 8, 16];
$orders = array_map(function($item) {
    return "id = {$item} desc";
}, $ids);
$rawOrder = implode(', ', $orders);

$prod = Produto::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderByRaw($rawOrder)->get();
```

O `array_map` irá produzir um novo *array* onde cada elemento será uma regra da ordenação e o `implode` vai fazer com que este novo *array* gere uma *string* onde cada elemento é separado por uma vírgula.

Ou seja, o `map` vai gerar algo assim:

```
0 => "id = 12 desc"
1 => "id = 5 desc"
2 => "id = 1 desc"
3 => "id = 8 desc"
4 => "id = 16 desc"
```

E o implode vai gerar isto

```
"id = 12 desc, id = 5 desc, id = 1 desc, id = 8 desc, id = 16 desc"
```

Assim você pode usar a *string* `$rawOrder` no método `orderByRaw` do QueryBuilder.

---

Na verdade, dá até pra encurtar um pouco o código acumulando ordernações no `Builder`

```
$ids = [12, 5, 1, 8, 16];
$query = Produto::whereIn('id', $ids); 

foreach ($ids as $id) { 
    $query->orderByRaw("id = {$id} desc");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, inclusive eu testei aqui e deu certo também, acabei escolhendo a opção 5 do amigo ali, mas pra quem tiver com o mesmo problema, saibam que essa resposta também é válida.

Comment: @GabrielAugusto Tranquilo jovem, a ideia é a mesma, mas a opção dele ficou bem mais curta.

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade o MySQL tem uma opção para ORDENAR da menira que você está querendo que é a função `FIELD()` e no Laravel você pode usar o `orderByRaw`, onde você pode escrever uma instrução SQL, acho que fica mais simples fazer dessa maneira, seu código ficaria assim:

```
$produtos = Produto::whereIn('id', $ids)
        ->orderByRaw('FIELD(id,'.implode(",",$ids).')')
        ->get();
```

Acaba sendo uma maneira mais simples de fazer pois não precisa percorrer o array de ids nem o resultado e ordenar futuramente, assim resolve o problema de uma maneira mais legível. Apesar de as outras opções atenderem a necessidade.